# Is there a difference between a signed apk and the one residing in my bin folder?

Tags: android, apk

I need to export an APK to CD for my university coursework.

First of all I've done my whole project folder, and after coming into some problem trying to export a signed apk, I noticed it was in my project bin folder anyway.

Is there anything wrong with this apk? Is it runnable on other devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no difference, the apk should install and run on other devices.

Your apk may be signed with default keystore for debug build, or your own keystore depending on how you configured.

Answer (score 0):

Just for testing, you can use apk in bin folder. But to submit to playstore and all you need a signed apk. Try with another keystore or remove build automatically option while generating apk.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run APK of bin folder in any of the device for testing purpose . But if you want to Upload your APP to Palystore then you have to Export it(signed with release keystore) in this case APK of bin folder will not work .
Hope this info will be helpfil for you.